# 14.04_LTS and Remote Login (UCCS)?

Tags: 14.04, login, remote, rdp, landscape

Upgraded my laptop to 14.04_LTS from 13.10 not long ago and decided to check that "Remote Login" thingy I have on the login screen (never used it before and I'm pretty new to Ubuntu)

So I tried to add a server after logging in via my Ubuntu One account, some IP address available on my LAN for a RDP server (URL via HTTP ?? And why RDP protocol only?) but when I try to login into the "Remote Login" it won't just work, it refuses my Ubuntu One credentials!

From what I can find on the WEB is it me or that option is not available anymore anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an experimental feature, meant for thin clients. It never reached production status.

Answer (score 2):

I never managed to get this feature running myself.

Development on launchpad seems to be stopped for this feature. Last activity dates back to 2012. I found the following bug for [lightdm-remote-session-uccsconfigure (Ubuntu)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm-remote-session-uccsconfigure)

> Bug #1301897 UCCS configure should be dropped

Bug Description:

> The UCCS configure feature, part of the remote login mechanism should be phased out. It was a testbed for the whole feature.
>   Right now we have disabled remote login by default, but kept it as an implementation reference for enterprises interested in such a solution.

I suppose the remote login feature has been silently deprecated. Please correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I didn't stumble upon this in my research! Since there's no feedback on it for now I'll keep this question on hold and monitor...